# Get variable variables in Twig

Tags: twig

How to get the contents of the **variable variables** in **Twig**?

*Php analogue*: `$$var`

Thanks.

Agreed :{{ _context[var_name] }}

Comment: It depends on the context you'd like to use the variable. Is this a variable you're passing to Twig you're trying to access? Or is an array or object attribute? There is a couple questions here in S.O. on this same matter.

Comment: Yes, the variable is passed from the controller, and her name is formed in a template

Comment: You could try `{{ attribute(_context, var_name) }}`. See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html